# How to determine port number of Arduino for pySerial in macOS

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, macos-mojave, usbserial

I would like to know how to determine the port number of the Arduino nano that is connected to my macbook if I will use it in Python.

Tools>Port in Arduino IDE

```
/dev/cu.usbserial-A900afrI
```

I have this code in my .py file

```
import serial

a = serial.Serial('A900afrI', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
```

I want to know what port should I replace 'A9000afrI' with because I get an error which is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cievlh/Desktop/Python/python_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'A900afrI'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyserial.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = serial.Serial('A900afrI', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
  File "/Users/cievlh/Desktop/Python/python_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/Users/cievlh/Desktop/Python/python_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port A900afrI: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'A900afrI'
(python_env)
```

Comment: `/dev/cu.usbserial-A900afrI`?

Comment: It is the port of the Arduino when you check it in the Arduino IDE if you click 'Tools' in the menu bar

Comment: Did you try the whole string not just the `A900afrI`?

Comment: I did found out about it earlier, I tried including '/dev/cu.usbserial-'. Just forgot to post the solution my post here here. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, just included the whole string according to gre_gor.

```
import serial

a = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-A900afrI', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is actually for an Arduino clone: I think they are the same.

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
#Find USB Port
def find_port():  #Finds which port the arduino is plugged into
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for p in ports:
        if '0403' in p[2]: #unique to Osepp Uno (arduino clone)                
            return p[0]
```