# How to retrieve USB-to-serial address?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, ubuntu, usbserial

## ISSUE

Pyserial: A USB serial device has different addresses depending on whether I install it to a desktop (Catalina) or laptop (High Sierra):

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial', 9600) #OSX High-Sierra
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-1D120', 9600) #OSX Catalina
```

Is there a method to use a wildcard?  `/dev/su.usbseria*`.  The goal is one line of code that will handle either case.

Any insight as to why `-1D120` was appended, is appreciated.

## REFERENCES

- [Listing available com ports with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090503/listing-available-com-ports-with-python)
- [per user zrzka:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584801/4953146)

Example

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
#Find USB Port
def find_port():  #Finds which port the arduino is plugged into
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for p in ports:
        if '0403' in p[2]: #unique to Osepp Uno (arduino clone)                
            return p[0]
```

Assume that the target string (regular expression) is of the format:

> /dev/cu.usbserial**************

How would the above snippet of code be modified to trap and return the USB serial device?

Comment: Iterate over available ports (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584801/581190)) and choose the one you'd like to use.

Comment: @zrzka Thanks for the reference.  Solution posted

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer was cut from the question and properly posted here.

Retrieve USB-to-serial address and open port

**YMMV**: mind the algorithm limitations.  Especially the trapping string: **if there is more than one instance found (trapped), the last trapped list item will be returned** => it may or may not be the intended target string.

```
import serial.tools.list_ports    
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports: 
    #print(p[0])  #p[0] => target string
    if 'usbserial' in p[0]: #OSX: Trap usbserial device  /dev/cu.usbserial-1D120              
        serAddr=p[0]
    if 'ttyUSB' in p[0]: #Ubuntu :Trap usbserial device  /dev/ttyUSB0
        serAddr=p[0]              

ser = serial.Serial(serAddr, 9600) # Open port at 9600 baud
```

A third untested trap for checking windows COM ports can be added:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports    
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports: 
    #print(p[0])  #p[0] => target string
    if 'usbserial' in p[0]: #OSX: Trap usbserial device  /dev/cu.usbserial-1D120              
        serAddr=p[0]
    if 'ttyUSB' in p[0]: #Ubuntu :Trap usbserial device  /dev/ttyUSB0
        serAddr=p[0]              
    if 'COM' in p[0]: #Windows :Trap usbserial device  COM3 COM7 etc.
        serAddr=p[0]
```